# Why doesn't my spring boot application render messages.properties in mustache templates

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, mustache

I want to build a spring boot web application with mustache templates that uses internationalization.

Following this guide https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization I tried a mini example with gradle and kotlin that works with thymeleaf templates but fails for mustache

In order to adapt the guide for mustache I did the following changes:

1. switch
   `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'` with 
   `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mustache'`
2. rename international.html to international.mustache
3. alter international.mustache like this

   `<html>
       <head>
           <title>Home</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <h1>{{#i18n}}greeting{{/i18n}} test</h1>
       </body>
   </html>`

A file messages.properties contains the line
`greeting=Hello! Welcome to our website!`

Just to provide all neccessary code here is my configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["com.example.translationtest.config"])
class AppConfig: WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    fun localeResolver(): LocaleResolver {
        val slr = SessionLocaleResolver()
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US)
        return slr
    }

    @Bean
    fun localeChangeInterceptor(): LocaleChangeInterceptor {
        val lci = LocaleChangeInterceptor()
        lci.paramName = "lang"
        return lci
    }

    override fun addInterceptors(registry: InterceptorRegistry) {
         registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor())
    }
}
```

When I visit the page in the browser I only see the string `test` 
While I would expect to see

`Hello! Welcome to our website! test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JMustache](https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache), which is what `spring-boot-starter-mustache` uses, does not provide any internationalization support out of the box. The `{{#i18n}}greeting{{/i18n}}` in your template is ignored as JMustache doesn't recognize `i18n`.

As documented in its readme, you can implement internationalisation support using a `Mustache.Lamda`:

> You can also obtain the results of the fragment execution to do things like internationalization or caching:
>
> ```java
> Object ctx = new Object() {
>     Mustache.Lambda i18n = new Mustache.Lambda() {
>         public void execute (Template.Fragment frag, Writer out) throws IOException {
>             String key = frag.execute();
>             String text = // look up key in i18n system
>             out.write(text);
>         }
>     };
> };
> ```
>
> ```html
> // template might look something like:
> <h2>{{#i18n}}title{{/i18n}</h2>
> {{#i18n}}welcome_msg{{/i18n}}
> ```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. That doesn't seem very elegant. And besides not knowing where to put this lambda at the moment, I'm not sure I want to implement a system to lookup i18n values. I'm not sure. Should I still accept the answer?

Comment: Whether or not you accept that answer is, of course, up to you. The problem that you're facing is a side-effect of choosing to use Mustache rather than a template engine with more features (and more complexity) such as Thymeleaf. If you're looking for something with a rich set of features that does a lot for you out of the box, there are choices that are a better fit than Mustache. Thymeleaf, as used by the tutorial you were following, is the most popular.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently evaluating my options. Since your answer is technically correct, I will accept, event though I didn't try it :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding on [Andy Winlkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) answer and Joining on [Rotzlucky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841338/rotzlucky) expectatives I share what I have done to achieve JMustache internacionalization working.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class InternacionalizationAdvice {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource message;

    @ModelAttribute("i18n")
    public Mustache.Lambda i18n(Locale locale){
        return (frag, out) -> {
            String body = frag.execute();
            String message = this.message.getMessage(body, null, locale);
            out.write(message);
        };
    }
}
```